# How to set token tax fee?

Tags: solana-program, spl-token, spl-token-program

In certain tokens on others blockchains, people who are selling/buying/transferring the tokens will be hit by a 10% or more penalty tax fee on the transactions set by token creator. Some of the collected tax fees are distributed to:

1. Holders
2. Reward pool: Some of the tokens received as tax fee and another coin (BNB, BUSD, ETH, etc) are taken. And these coins are distributed proportionally to the holders.
3. Token Burn: Some of the tokens cut as a tax fee are burned.
4. Add liquidity pool: Tokens deducted as tax fee are added to the liquidity pool.
5. Marketing and dev wallet

Can a developer of tokens set a fee to do that with SPL token on Solana blockchain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In token-2022, there's the ability to collect a transfer fee on every token movement. You can set a transfer fee on your token, and then use another program to collect fees and distribute / burn them as you see fit.

You can find more information about transfer fees at https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/extensions#transfer-fees

With the older token program, you can only do this by "managing" the token through a program that keeps the tokens frozen. This program unfreezes, performs actions, and then refreezes the token.  You can find an example program at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/master/managed-token